# Read the Word File, identify headings,& get the content

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I want to **compare the heading of a word file with string, if it matches , then it displays it content**
suppose a word file content 2-4 Paragraphs with heading, I want that it compare the heading with the string & display the content using C#

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how far you have gotten on the project, but this is how you can compare the heading to your selected string then display the header content.

```
char[] separ = new char[]{' '};
string[] yourSelectedHeaderText = YourString.Split(separ.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyString)
string[] docHeader = HeaderSting.Split(separ,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyString);

for(int i=0; i< docHeader.Length;i++){
   if(docHeader[i] == yourSelectHeaderText[i]){
      Console.WriteLine(docHeader[i].ToString());
   }
}
```

Setting everything up into arrays or some kind of collection to iterate through is what you would want to do first, then I iterated through the header Strings one by one, under that iteration I added an if statement that would catch the matching header with your selected string. Inside the if statement we have the line that will display the string in your console.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like it probably solves the problem - but it'd be good if you could also provide an explanation for why/how this solves the problem. Lots of people on Stack Overflow are real newbies and could learn something from your expertise. Don't forget that what may seem obvious to you, may not be to them :)